# Is rounds in a cryptography algorithm same as iterating the algorithm?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, algorithm

In a cryptography algorithm such as AES or DES, does the number of rounds mean same as iterating the algorithm?

Example:

```
c= "plaintext";
for(int i=0;i<5; i++)
{
 c = AES(c , "key"); 
}
```

Where c holds the cipher text produced after 5 iterations.

If No, then

1.What exactly a round is?

2.Does iteration improves the security of the information being encrypted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is No.

1. "Rounds" are internal operations inside the AES (or DES) algorithm.  These algorithms use a mixing function that is repeated internally a defined number of times.  Each round increases "diffusion", which is how a change in one bit of key material or ciphertext causes changes to multiple bits across the entire block.  The number of rounds is selected to ensure that diffusion is distributed evenly across the entire block, so that a 1 bit change in input should cause about 50% of the bits in the output block to flip.
   The algorithm specification will define the standard number of rounds; i.e. 10 rounds for AES-128, 12 rounds for AES-192, and 14 rounds for AES-256.  Each round of AES uses a complex set of routines including S-box substitutions, row shifting, column mixing, and subkey addition. Other algorithms are designed to use very simple mixing functions, and rely on a high number of rounds for diffusion.  For example Skein uses just three primitive operators, addition, rotation, and XOR, and achieves diffusion by using 72 rounds.
   Sometimes you read about people cryptanalyzing "a reduced round variant of AES".  They are talking about attacking a modified form of the encryption algorithm.  These reduced-round attacks may or may not indicate a weakness in the published, full-round algorithm.
2. It may help security slightly, it may do nothing, or it may actually harm security!  It depends on how it's implemented.  Cases where it helps are in protocols like PBKDF2, Argon2, or BALLOON hashing, where the increased number of iterations is designed to make breaking one use of the algorithm take a lot of resources, slowing down attacks.  Cases where it could harm include certain ciphers where a second encryption might result in a decryption of the first! (That's the case with certain block cipher modes of operation, such as ECB or CTR.) And there are cases where the intersection of two encryptions can yield information about the key.

In general, randomly throwing cryptographic algorithms at a problem in hopes of making it "better" is an extremely risky approach, and is not recommended.

Comment: Sir cud u plz provide link to some resources that have proved  using multiple symmetric key algorithm resulting into a security compromise.

Comment: @Abhi - from [here](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/ctr/ctr-spec.pdf) `Therefore, decryption is the same as encryption with M and C interchanged` - So performing the encryption an even number of times will leave the message in clear-text. This is for AES in CTR mode.

Comment: You may require additional steps as well. Rounds may e.g. depends on a subkey instead of the original key. If you add rounds you may need to define how the additional subkeys are generated.

Comment: Thnx everyone 4 clearing the doubts......